# Bash file while loop isnt running well

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using the Ubuntu terminal emulator for Windows 10 to try learn the Linux terminal.

I have this code:

```
cat > c1.sh
echo Give me your name!
read name
echo How many times do you want your laptop to print out your name?
read numberOfLoops
i=0
while [ $i -lt $numberOfLoops ]
do
echo $name
i=$i+1
done
#end
```

I create the executable file and begin running it:

```
./c1.sh
 Give me your name!
 Root
 How many times do you want your laptop to print out your name?
 3
 Root
 ./c1.sh: line 6: [: 0+1: integer expression expected
```

It prints out the name `Root` "once" as it should but then it stops running and prints out the message `./c1.sh: line 6: [: 0+1: integer expression expected`. However if there was a issue with the `while` loop then it wouldn't print out the first time `Root` but it does so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not numeric addition:

```
i=$i+1
```

It's string concatenation. If `$i` is `0`, after the assignment it's `0+1`.

This is numeric addition in bash:

```
((i=i+1))
```

or shorter

```
((++i))
```

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Although syntactically valid, the expression `i=$i+1` is a *string assignment*, so that the second time through the loop you are comparing literal string `0+1` to an integer `$numberOfLoops`

To get arithmetic evaluation, you can use `let i=$i+1`, `i=$((i+1))` or (in bash - for which you should add a `#!/bin/bash` shebang at the top of your script, `((i=i+1))` or even `((i++))`

If you are really using bash (rather than sh) it would probably be more idiomatic to use a C-style for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p 'Give me your name! ' name
read -r -p 'How many times do you want your laptop to print out your name? ' numberOfLoops

for ((i=0; i<numberOfLoops; i++)); do
  printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

See also the [Arithmetic Evaluation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#index-arithmetic-evaluation) section of the bash manual.

Comment: Ah Okay! thanks a lot.